# Simple Header File with Array SV.showVales(set2_1, SIZE2_1)

Tags: c++, arrays, header

I CORRECTED the mistake, but what I am really trying to do is get the data from the Header File, and not use the data in the main function. Thanks

I am new to this site, but would like some advice on how to re-arrange these files.

Here is the Header file:

```
#ifndef Prog_7_15_h
#define Prog_7_15_h

class Prog_7_15
{
    private:
        //Originally const int and int set2_1[8] were in private
    public:
    Prog_7_15();
    void showValues2(int [], int);
    const int SIZE2_1 = 8;
    const int SIZE2_2 = 5;
    int set2_1[8] = { 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40 }; // Not SIZE2_1  8
    int set2_2[5] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };
    ~Prog_7_15();
};

#endif // !Prog_7_15
```

//Here is the Prog_7_15.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Prog_7_15.h"
using namespace std;

Prog_7_15::Prog_7_15() { }

void Prog_7_15::showValues2(int num[], int size)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
        cout << num[index] << "\t";
    cout << endl;
}

Prog_7_15::~Prog_7_15() { }
```

Here is the Main **Idea.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Prog_7_15.h"
using namespace std;

void showValues(int[], int);

int main()
{
    Prog_7_15 SV;

    const int SIZE1 = 8;  //This part works!
    const int SIZE2 = 5;

    int set1[SIZE1] = { 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40 };
    int set2[SIZE2] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };

    showValues(set1, SIZE1);

    showValues(set2, SIZE2);

    SV.showValues2( set1, SIZE1 );  // work!  
    //Played around with int [], int and just  int, int and ()
    SV.showValues2(set2_1, SIZE2_1);  //Does NOT WORK

    return 0;
}

void showValues(int nums[], int size)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
        cout << nums[index] << "\t";
    cout << endl;
}
```

I would like to find out why the main function works, and yet the header file does not work. Any explaining would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

First off, your ***showValues2*** function needs to be part of your ***Prog_7_15*** class.

From this:

```
void showValues2(int num[], int size)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
        cout << num[index] << "\t";
    cout << endl;
}
```

To this:

```
void Prog_7_15::showValues2(int num[], int size)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
        cout << num[index] << "\t";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Your constructor and deconstructor syntactically correct, so I'm assuming you just forgot this!

Next, this line:

```
SV.showValues2( int [],int );
```

While these are the types that *Prog_7_15*'s *showValues2* wants, you need to pass in **variables** of those types to make it work. You did it correctly with *showValues* earlier! *showValues2* being class function does not change how that function takes in parameters.

The fix:

```
SV.showValues2(set1, SIZE1);
```

---

So the problem has been updated on how to use Prog_7_15's `set2_1` (or `set2_2`) and `SIZE2_1` (or `SIZE2_2`).

These variables being in a header file does not matter; you just need to remember to include the said header file. What's stopping you is that your variables are part of the `Prog_7_15` **class**.

You can't use the `set2` and `SIZE2` variables until you make an **object** of the `Proj_7_15` class. Luckily, you already did with `SV` at this line:

```
Prog_7_15 SV;
```

Now, you have access to all of Prog_7_15's (public) functions and variables through the object `SV`.

To access a class' functions and variables, all you need to do is put a `.` after an object you made. You can see the class function showValues2 working this way.

So for example, if you want to use the variable set2_1 in a function, all you need to do is write it like this:

```
random_function_name(SV.set2_1);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I fixed it, but what I would really like is to use the data in the Header File.

```
    SV.showValues2(set2_1, SIZE2_1);  //Does not Work Data in the Header File
SV.showValues2(set1, SIZE1); //Works!
```

set2_1, SIZE_1 IS IN THE Header file and I am trying to put just functions in the main function.

Thanks again